# How to hide NavigationBar after keyboard closing. Android 6.0.1. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

[image: The NavigatorBar opened while using the keyboard and then it didn't close]We made a fullscreen application and it works correctly but when we focus on the TextField widget (open keyboard) and then close it, NavigationBar doesn't hide.
Android version 6.0.1.
We tried:

1. Keyboard visibility packages (all).
2. Restarted (every time) the app after keyboard calls.
3. Called methods of different fullscreen packages.
4. Changed AndroidManifest:

- android:windowSoftInputMode
- android:theme

*We can't update the Android version.

Comment: Can you add some code snippets?

Comment: @SalihCan It will be too much code snippets